# C# Complains that an Interface Method is not Implemented

Tags: c#

```
namespace RepositoryFactory.Interface
{
    public interface ISelectionFactory<TIdentityObject> 
    {

        DbCommand ConstructSelectCommand(Database db, TIdentityObject idObject);
    }
}


namespace SafetypadDAL
{
    public class T_INCIDENT_SelectFactory:ISelectionFactory<T_INCIDENT>
    {
        public DbCommand ConstructSelectCommand(Database db, T_INCIDENT idObject)
        {
            //my business codes will be here

            return command;
        }
    }
}
```

This is that program.

Here you can not find any wrong signature.

Comment: Error message could not be clearer: 'SafetypadDAL.T_INCIDENT_SelectFactory' does not implement interface member 'RepositoryFactory.Interface.ISelectionFactory<SafetypadDTO.T_INCIDENT

Comment: In other words, you may think you implemented the correct method, but you did not. Carefully check to make sure your method takes the correct parameter types, and that you've spelled the method name correctly.

Comment: Put back your original question and updates through it so other users will be able to follow.  Also marking an answer as accepted would help others from coming here and not realising that the question has already been answered.

Comment: @John: did you reply to the correct question?

Answer (score 4):

You may have implemented a method called `ConstructSelectCommand` but with the wrong signature, so it wouldn't match the method.

If you're using VS2005 or later, click in the interface name in your class declaration, and press Ctrl and period (dot). It will offer to generate the method stubs for you.

If you really, really think you've done the right thing, please post your declaration of that method. Are you sure you've made it public, for instance? (Or implemented the interface explicitly, of course.)

EDIT: Is it possible that `Database` in the two signatures refer to different types? What happens if you try what I suggested in terms of getting Visual Studio to generate the stub?

Comment: Actually, i had generated the signature using Visual Studio Intelligence only.

Comment: Hmm... usually Visual Studio uses the full names of the types (including namespace). Did you remove the namespace yourself? If you hover over "Database" what type does it show?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't implemented it. Post the relevant part of the code, if you like. Probably you can event instruct your IDE to attempt the implementation for you, just to get the exact signature.